# Can I have multiple jest tests asserting on a single result?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

I wanted to write many small tests that assert on a single `result` that's only calculated once, so I wrote this structure:

(note the outer `beforeAll` and `beforeEach`, and the inner `beforeAll`s)

```
describe("service", ()=>{
  beforeAll(async ()=>{
    await initDb()
  })

  beforeEach(async ()=>{
    await resetConnection()
  })

  afterEach(async ()=>{
    await cleanDb()
  })

  describe("#getDetails", ()=>{
    describe("with a normal user", ()=>{
      let result

      beforeAll(async ()=>{
        const user = await createDbUserEntity()
        result = await service.getDetails(user)
      })

      it("should have a count of 1", ()=>{
        expect(result.count).toEqual(1)
      })

      it("should not have a relationship", ()=>{
        expect(result.rel).toNotBeDefined()
      })
    })

    describe("with two related users", ()=>{
      let result

      beforeAll(async ()=>{
        const user = await createDbUser({related: createDbUser()})
        result = await service.getDetails(user)
      })

      it("should have a count of 2", ()=>{
        expect(result.count).toEqual(1)
      })

      it("should have a relationship", ()=>{
        expect(result.rel).toEqual({foo:"bar"})
      })
    })

  })
})
```

Unfortunately the inner `beforeAll` gets run before the outer `beforeEach`, so nothing actually works, because the connection hasn't been reset when the inner beforeAll runs.

Is there a way to use Jest to write these tiny tests I want? Where `result` is only calculated once for a group of tests, so I can write tests that are phrased exactly how my organization thinks about our business-rules?

Because with small tests like that the test-report ends up with nice names like "*service #getDetails with two related users should have a count of 2*" which speaks exactly to my org's domain knowledge.

Comment: Could you just move the `resetConnection` to the same `beforeAll`?

Comment: Are you actually making API calls with your tests?

Comment: @Pytth I could move things yes, but the outer describe sets the context "these all use the test-DB", and the inner describe sets the context "these tests are for getDetails method", if I merge beforeAll's I mess up that separation of concerns. I'd really like to keep the describe-blocks such that they each contribute a meaningful context.

Comment: are those other calls async? you can return a promise from those callbacks

Comment: @Pytth the tests are backed by a test-DB, so here the implementation of `service.getDetails()` would make use of the DB. The actual code has setup methods to create DB entities but I figured that code isn't so important for my example. Happy to addd more context if you say my description so far isn't meaningful enough.

Comment: @DanielA.White all the calls are actually async, but I didn't show that in this example as I don't think it has an impact. But yes initDB, connections, cleanup, and service call are all async.